# What is the best practice to get timeseries line plot in dataframe or list contains missing value in pyspark?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pyspark, seaborn, missing-data

Credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098537/seaborn-avoid-plotting-missing-values-line-plot), I have spark dataframe and I want to plot one of the columns based on the timestamp column. The problem is interesting column contains the missing values (`Null`) and I would like not to draw missing values.

The excerpt of my data frame is as below which can be created easily by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59547508/10452700) :

```
# +---------------------+-------+
# |      timestamp      |  col1 |
# +---------------------+-------+
# | 2021-05-10 19:48:36 |  714  |
# | 2021-05-10 15:34:26 |  Null |
# | 2021-05-10 14:08:31 |  634  |
# | 2021-05-10 20:29:46 |  8453 |
# | 2021-05-10 19:48:36 |  Null |
# | 2021-05-10 00:20:25 |  3825 |
# +---------------------+-------+
```

Apart from using *interpolation* or *imputation* of the column contains missing values suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077639/pyspark-interpolation-of-missing-values-in-pyspark-dataframe-observed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097633/imputing-missing-values-using-a-linear-regression-in-python), I would like to still *keep the gaps* and *not touch nature of data* in visualization like the following example:
[image: img]

What I tried was to use the following trick to convert data from pyspark into Pandas using `toPandas()` and then apply pythonic scripts for plotting deploying `seaborn` or `matplotlib` offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098537/seaborn-avoid-plotting-missing-values-line-plot) particularly `sns.pointplot()` & `sns.lineplot()`.

```py
#read the data
sdf = spark.read.parquet(INPUT_PATH)
#Pandas
pdf = sdf.toPandas()
```

The problem with this trick is I'm not using Spark and its *workers* power and for visualizing the big data (circa 8M records) it takes so long time to catch the plot and monitor outliers over the available `timestamp` window for reasoning *outlier detection* methods outputs.

Any help to update solutions for this problem will be appreciated!

Comment: Would it be an option to take a [sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample.html) of the data before plotting?

Comment: @werner I used it already since I couldn't plot the whole data, but it's not really an option for this case. Since I might skip that event (outlier) when randomly sampled. The aim is to plot all data points despite their gaps due to missing values. I was thinking of replacing missing values with unique fixed values (e.g. 0.123456) and plot those parts as the same colour as background like white `#FFFFFF`.